# Programmatically trigger a key events in a JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keyevent

How do I programmatically trigger a key pressed event on a `JTextField` that is listening for events on the <kbd>ENTER</kbd>?

The listener for key events on my `JTextField` is declared as follows:

```
myTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you call directly `doStuff()`?

Comment: don´t get your problem, it is working. do you get any error?

Comment: Use an Actionlistener instead of and KeyAdapter and it should work

Comment: There is normally no need to add a `KeyListener` to a `JTextField`. You have `DocumentListener`s, `DocumentFilter`s and `ActionListener`s at your disposal. In this case you would need the `ActionListener` which is automatically triggered when pressing ENTER

Comment: -1 until you explain _what_ you want to achieve

Comment: @kleopatra Ok, so what I want to achieve is to call whatever code is assigned to the ENTER key. Only thing I know is that the textfield will be listening for ENTER key events. 
The code I wrote above is just to show how my textfield has its key listener declared. It is not the part I'm actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Do not use `KeyListener` on `JTextField` simply add `ActionListener` which will be triggered when <kbd>ENTER</kbd> is pressed (thank you @robin +1 for advice)

  ```
  JTextField textField = new JTextField();

  textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
           //do stuff here when enter pressed
      }
  });
  ```
- To trigger `KeyEvent` use `requestFocusInWindow()` on component and use `Robot` class to simulate key press

Like so:

```
textField.requestFocusInWindow();

try { 
    Robot robot = new Robot(); 

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 
} catch (AWTException e) { 
e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Example:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JTextField textField = new JTextField();

                textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        System.out.println("Here..");
                    }
                });
                frame.add(textField);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);

                textField.requestFocusInWindow();

                try {
                    Robot robot = new Robot();

                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                } catch (AWTException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

As others like @Robin and @mKorbel have suggested you might want a `DocumentListener`/`DocumentFiler` (Filter allows validation before `JTextField` is updated).

You will need this in the event of data validation IMO.

see this similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517057/how-to-make-cursor-can-enter-jtextfield-but-the-only-way-to-give-it-a-text-is-cl/13517107#13517107)

it shows how to add a `DocumentFilter` to a `JTextField` for data validation. The reason for document filter is as I said allows validation before chnage is shown which is more useful IMO

Comment: -1 There is already a binding for the ENTER key. It will trigger the `ActionListener` attached to the text field. Overriding this might cause subtle issues

Comment: @Robin I see your point +1 thank you for the knowlegde.. updated code

Comment: `How do I problematically trigger a key pressed event on a JTextField` :-) I bet that is only about DocumentListener, even ActionListner returns whole Document

Comment: @mKorbel But Why go through all of that if we simply want to catch enter pressed  and can via actionListener. I guess you are under the assumption the OP is performing validation checks... +1 this would be the way to go than

Comment: @David Kroukamp I'm "confused" from this question, better could be waiting for OPs whatever, nobody knows

Comment: @mKorbel true, though I'd lean with `DocumentFilter` and not `Listener` if it is the case

Comment: If anyone else is wondering why the example keeps repeating the enter key, it is because robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) is never called.

Answer (score 4):

You can construct Event by yourself and then call dispatchEvent on JTextField.

```
  KeyEvent keyEvent = new KeyEvent(...); //create
  myTextField.dispatchEvent();
```

For parameters of KeyEvent can refer [KeyEvent constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html)

Comment: I bet that is only about DocumentListener, dispatchEvent(); could be usefull to simulating DocumentListener from KeyListener, (now coming reason why I commenting...) or your answer going another direction, then have to add more detailed description about your idea

Comment: @mKorbel, can you please let me know the logical chain how you come up to DocumentListener? Because I have never used it and here it is never mentioned. But dispatchEvent() I have used for JScrollPane and it worked fine. Do you think it is not suitable in this case?

Comment: key event are implemented in Document, Document is model for JTextComponents, you can to listening all typed chars by add DocumentListener :-) never add KeyListener (my view) to Swing *JComponents, only if is there real reason e.i. combinations of 4-5 keys are pressed or for another ZOO came from keyboard

Comment: @mKorbel, ok thanks, I would need to read about internals of JTextComponent. However, if the author still wants to use the code he provided us, I guess my answer might be useful to him.

Comment: hehehe I see, then OP will returns with a few question or to creating mess,

Comment: For JUnit purpose you can customize you JTextField as explained here   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336703/simulate-key-press-in-junit-tests/54950578#54950578