# JTextField validation

Tags: java, swing, validation, jtextfield

I wrote my own InputVerifier for JTextField and it works fine. Now I would like to "force" validation on this text field when user clicks a button. Is it possible to do?

Comment: validations could be in JTextField, not from JButton, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: +1 mKorbel and Mad comments...See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563042/programmatically-trigger-a-key-events-in-a-jtextfield/13563314#13563314) similar question/answer. It shows use how to programmatically trigger `JTextField` *enter* key pressed using Robot class and `requestFocusInWindow()`, though I think all you will need is changing focus to the textfield and to another component via `requestFocusInWindow()`...

Comment: The Java docs state *"Before focus is transfered to another Swing component that requests it, the input verifier's shouldYieldFocus method is called. Focus is transfered only if that method returns true"*

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Changing focus back and forth triggers text field validation. Please write an answer so I can mark it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added as answer as @JarekMazur said it solved the problem.

Re-iterating my comment:

+1 @MadProgrammer for the docs

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563042/programmatically-trigger-a-key-events-in-a-jtextfield/13563314#13563314) similar question/answer. It shows use how to programmatically trigger `JTextField` <kbd>enter</kbd> key pressed using `Robot` class and [`requestFocusInWindow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow%28%29), though I think you would only need the latter.

Try changing `JTextField` focus using [`requestFocusInWindow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow%28%29).

You would initially request focus on the `JTextField` and than to another component in order to fire the `Input Verifier` [`shouldYieldFocus`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html#shouldYieldFocus%28javax.swing.JComponent%29) method.

Comment: This looks like a workaround. If I have several controls with verifiers should I transfer focus to all of them sequentially? It would be nice if I could fire a method like `verifyAll`. Nothing like that in Swing?