# Java Swing | Key listener not responding at all

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

Im trying to get my KeyEvent working. Sadly the `keyTyped(KeyEvent e)` isnt responding at all. :)

I implemented the KeyEvnet to my class.

I assigned the listener like following:

```
JTextfield searchBar = new JTextField();
searchBar.addKeyListener( this );
```

My key event looks like this:

```
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        System.out.println("pressed");
        try {
            int browser = getSelectBrowser().getSelectedIndex();
            logic.search( searchBar.getText(), searchInfo, browser, isURL );
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            System.out.println( "Pressed fail" );
        }
        this.repaint();
    }
}
```

I also tried the Listener in a second test Gui and were it also does not work.

:-)

Comment: "*Does not work*" is not an acceptable problem description. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you tried putting a `System.out.println(...)` outside your `if`?

Comment: @Tiz System.out.println(...) is just to check if it actually went through the listener ;) It should work with a println().

Comment: @itknocks Yeah, I know. My point was that you won't see the print out **unless enter is pressed**. Putting the `println` outside the `if` will tell you if the method is called for other keys.

Comment: @Tiz oh sorry i miss understood your answer. when I put it outside of the 'if' ieverything I press prints me a 0

Comment: @itknocks are you specifically trying to use the enter key, or are you looking to handle all key presses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "keyPressed" instead of "keyTyped". keyTyped listens only on alphanumeric chars

Comment: use "keyPressed" instead of "keyTyped". keyTyped listens only on alphanumeric chars

Answer (score 0):

You wont see this listener called when you press enter, so your `println` will never be called. Pressing enter on a `JTextField` will call the attached `ActionListener`, if there is one.

To get this working, add an `ActionListener` to the text field and put the code you want to run when enter is pressed in there.

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563042/programmatically-trigger-a-key-events-in-a-jtextfield). Thanks to [tak3shi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1349927/tak3shi) for linking that in the comments.