# Form validation for JTextfield in Java?

Tags: java, swing, validation, jtextfield

Is there an easy way to `validate` a group of `JTextFields` in `Java`. I am currently using `sqlite manager`, `neatbeans IDE` to create a simple form that collects information to add a job into the database. I realise there is too many JTextFields. How can I validate each JTextFields either through sqllite throwing an exception error which can be customised, or maybe in Neatbeans through properties dialogue box. Validation is to be presence check, i.e. has a value been entered. Custom validation message?

Answer (score 9):

Use an `InputVerifier`, as shown in [*How to Use the Focus Subsystem : Validating Input*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification). There's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11818946/230513), among [others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11818080/230513).

Answer (score 5):

+1 t trashgods answer.

You could also use:

- [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html)/[`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) and add it to `JTextField`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058505/jtextfield-accept-only-alphabet-and-white-space/14060047#14060047) for an example and this [variation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517057/how-to-make-cursor-can-enter-jtextfield-but-the-only-way-to-give-it-a-text-is-cl/13517107#13517107).

`DocumentFilter` allows you to validate text before showing changes i.e by calling `super.XXX` implementation of overridden method after validating text successfully) where as `DocumentListener` does not. It usually in most cases better to settle for `DocumentFilter`.

See here for more help:

- [How to Write a Document Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)
- [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)

or alternatively:

- `JFormattedTextField` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881301/best-way-to-constrain-user-to-enter-a-time-in-a-jtextfield/11881523#11881523) for an example.