# Java GUI better to remove or setVisible(false)?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am coding up a relatively simple GUI application in Java using widgets from the Swing library. What is the common practice for 'conditionally' displaying certain items? Is it to `.setVisible(false)` on things that we want to temporarily hide; or is it to `.add` items as they are needed and then removing them when they are not to be shown any more?

Comment: I'd tend to use a `CardLayout` (or in other words, neither of the above)..

Comment: for me, I would change visibility

Comment: *"..for 'conditionally' displaying certain items"*  And don't forget you can conditionally *enable* certain items.  What is the actual use-case here?

Comment: @AndrewThompson time to investigate `CardLayout` it looks like. Right now I'm using `BoxLayout` as all I really need is for everything to stack on top of each other.

Comment: It's primary the designer opinion. And it particularly depends on the user requirements.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The application is a journey-finder for a simplified bus system. So there are text boxes to input a startStation, an endStation and a time, and I'm outputting the fastest journey (as just a string). I need to display (multiple) error messages that must go away when things are correct obviously; and there is a `JPanel` of stuff for editting a journey only after a journey has been computed.

Comment: Once I bookmarked this wonderful answer by @DavidKroukamp , of whose link is [drawing warning symbols during form validation in Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14170292/1057230). No doubt, I did liked the contents in the answer, and hopefully it might add somethingy to your knowledge as well :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually such things depend on the designer's opinion, however it depends what what exactly you're trying to show/hide.

If you want to display a widget after a certain condition/method returns true then just use setVisible(true), this allows you to easily toggle on/off.

If you want to display the widget only once(and not hide it ever again) then just .add it when you need to so that it's displayed(condition/method).

All boils down to preference

Answer (score 5):

> " I need to display (multiple) error messages that must go away when things are correct obviously"

Not sure how you're displaying your error messages, but seems like a simple `JLabel` with the simple use of `setText()` would be appropriate. Trying to add an remove or set visible will mess with the layout, causing a constantly changing layout, which may be undesirable or not very user friendly. Something as simple as;

```
String errorMessage = "Error";
String noErrorMessage = "  ";

....
if (error) {
    errorLabel.setText(errorMessage);
} else {
    errorLabel.setText(noErrorMessage);
}
```

I use the space for `noErrorMessage` as having no space will affect the preferred size and still effect the layout