# DecimalFormat point and comma as decimalSeparator

Tags: java, number-formatting, decimalformat

i once have written this code to format the input of `JFormattedTextField`

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
NumberFormatter nf = new NumberFormatter(decimalFormat);
nf.setValueClass(Double.class);
nf.setAllowsInvalid(true);
nf.setOverwriteMode(false);
tfPreisIntern = new JFormattedTextField(nf);
```

after some time i realized the problem that occurs if the user enters for example `4,50` instead of `4.50` then the value is set to `4.00` instead of `4.50` or `4,50`. i think its an problem of my `DecimalFormat`. now my question is, is it possible to have comma and point as possible decimal separator? workarounds are also okay

my method to convert the value from the `JFormattedTextField` into `BigDecimal`:

```
public static BigDecimal getBigDecimal(Object value) {
    BigDecimal ret = null;
    if (value != null) {
        if (value instanceof BigDecimal) {
            ret = (BigDecimal) value;
        } else if (value instanceof String) {
            ret = new BigDecimal((String) value);
        } else if (value instanceof BigInteger) {
            ret = new BigDecimal((BigInteger) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Number) {
            ret = new BigDecimal(((Number) value).doubleValue());
        } else {
            throw new ClassCastException("Not possible to coerce [" + value + "] from class " + value.getClass()
                    + " into a BigDecimal.");
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

the problem with an comma i see here is that the constructor `BigDecimal(string)` only allows a decimal point and not a comma

EDIT:

now trying with `MaskFormatter` like this:

```
    MaskFormatter mask = new MaskFormatter("*#.##");
    mask.setPlaceholderCharacter(' ');
    mask.setCommitsOnValidEdit(false);
```

but i can't enter values like `2.50`. this only works if i use a mask like `#.##`. yet i need to have the possibility of values with 1 and 2 digits before the dot

Comment: I guess the `setAllowsInvalid(true)` will permit to parse and invalid value but will give you the closest value possible, using a `comma`, only the left part will match so it can't retrieve the `.50`. I don't have documentation (yet) to write an answer about that

Comment: About your edit, I had a similar problem not so long ago, luckily for me, the format was only `"123456.789"` or `"123456,789"`, so only a decimal separator, so I simply replace `,` with `.` to match the `BigDecimal` requirements, but if there is a chance you get `"123,456.789"`, you can't use that anymore.

Comment: @AxelH this would work, but the textfield should also always show the posted decimal format. i also thought about this solution, but i can't get it to work as i have to change everything to normal JTextFields and then many methods don't work as intended

Comment: As said in the answer comments, you might want to follow this [guide on formatted textfield](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html). This might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you check the Oracle [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) you can find that:

- for **formatting** it is possible to *alter* the formatting symbols, but
- for **parsing** there is no such thing.

And that makes a lot of sense: you are simply asking "I want the user to be able all kind of inconsistent data; and code shall magically turn that into what the user meant".

One way to improve the user experience: instead of using a formatted text field; you could simply allow the user to enter **strings**. And then you write **validators** that allow for that "magic" to happen.

In other words: if you want that "4,59" and "4.59" should result as the same thing, then you need to write code for that. Which could be as simple as using `indexOf()` to figure if "." or "," is present in the incoming string (**ONCE**); and then try to use "formatted" parsing for each of the cases using different patterns. If you decide for that steep route into the abyss, start reading about `InputVerifiers` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170232/form-validation-for-jtextfield-in-java) for example.

But of course: that can turn out to be complicated; because as said; you are basically allowing the user to put in **whatever** data; and expect to *guess* what he means with that.

My personal two cent: put a lot of warnings/examples around that text field; and allow exactly **one** locale based kind of input. And slap users fingers when he violates that.

Comment: This is a bit more complication than that since some local use a `.` or `,` as thousand separator. `100,000.00`. But the idea is correct of course. To add a bit more information, the format use `.` as a _placeholder for decimal separator_. So it will be based on the local to match the correct separator

Comment: we can simply assume that thousands will never be entered and even if, there shouldn't be thousand separators. if i use this solution, i think ill need some help to rewrite a method which gives me a BigDecimal from different classes as i think the validation would have to happen there. the problem with the users is that some are english and some are german and therefore have different decimal Separators

Comment: @AxelH its an price field and therefore the fraction should only allow 2 digits and not more

Comment: @XtremeBaumer In financial, you have currencies with 3 digits (only a few) but also you can have price with 3, 6, 8 decimals. So this is not true everywhere unfortunatly. But this would work for a local system, like a store management or anything that doesn't handle fuel (3 decimal too)

Comment: i think i can work with a maskformatter, but i cant seem to get the last thing to work which would be having the format `##.##` and still displaying values like `2.50`. if i use format `#.##` then i can't display values like `12.30`. if you can give me the tip to make this work id be very thankful

Comment: You got my upvote for that; but unfortunately this is "too far away" from my current knowledge; and that would mean I have to start experimenting myself to find a solution (which might actually exist or not exist) ... and I fear my time so too limited to go for that today.