# How to validate the Input of the User in a Swing?

Tags: java, swing, validation, input

I have created a console Application and now I'm starting to convert it into a swing Application. I have one question and I searched many times for an answer but I didn't find any.

My application has an class which validates the input of the user and also if the input is wrong it gives a error msg into console. So what I try to do is, I have an Jtextfield and validate this input, if the input is wrong it should give me the error msg.

That's my Input class where the User is allowed to write

```
public class Input {

    private static BufferedReader eingabe = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    private Output output = new Output();
    
    private static String captureText() throws Exception {
        return eingabe.readLine();
    }
    public String formatInput() {
        boolean again = true;

        while (again) {
            try {
                String format = captureText();

                if (!format.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && !format.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                    again = true;
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                again = false;
                return format;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.output.formatInputWrong();
            }
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

That's my output class method

```
void formatInputWrong() {
    System.out.print("\nThe Format Input is wrong.");
           
}
```

**I just want to know can I use the Validation of the Input class or should I create a special class for the swing input validation because I know I can take out the Input of the JTextfield?**

Comment: It really depends on what type of fields you're trying to validate - you could use an `InputVerifier`, it's post validation process, or for text components a `DocumentListener` or `DocumentFilter`

Comment: You could also do post validation through an `ActionListener` attached to a `JButton`

Comment: Yeah I would make it with the button but the normal console Validation dont work am I right? So that code what I am posted is a example how my console validation worked.

Comment: Most GUIs are event driven frameworks, that is, something happens and you respond to it. It can take a little getting use to.  Basically, you won't need a loop of any kind (that's taken care for you) and you simply respond to the appropriate events when they a triggered

Answer (score 3):

Your error message now appears on the console. It looks like you want the message to appear in the GUI. As shown in [*How to Use the Focus Subsystem: Validating Input*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification), [`InputVerifier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) is a good choice. Because your implementation of `shouldYieldFocus()` is permitted to have sided effects, you can update a status display as needed. Starting from this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11818183/230513), the variation below adds a `JLabel` and conditions it in `shouldYieldFocus()` according to the result of calling `verify()`.

```
private static final String OK = "Values OK.";
private JLabel status = new JLabel(OK, JLabel.CENTER);
…
if (verify(input)) {
    …
    status.setText(OK);
    return true;
} else {
    …
    status.setText("Please enter a number.");
    return false;
}
```

A complementary approach might include a [`DocumentListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification), as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14171442/230513).

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/44861290/230513
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11818183/522444
 */
public class VerifierEg {

    private static final String ZERO = "0.0";
    private static final String OK = "Values OK.";
    private JTextField field1 = new JTextField(ZERO, 5);
    private JTextField field2 = new JTextField(ZERO, 5);
    private JTextField resultField = new JTextField(ZERO, 10);
    private JLabel status = new JLabel(OK, JLabel.CENTER);

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        resultField.setEditable(false);
        resultField.setFocusable(false);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        final JTextField[] fields = {field1, field2};

        mainPanel.add(field1);
        mainPanel.add(new JLabel(" x "));
        mainPanel.add(field2);
        mainPanel.add(new JLabel(" = "));
        mainPanel.add(resultField);

        for (JTextField field : fields) {
            field.setInputVerifier(new MyInputVerifier(field));
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("VerifierEg");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.add(status, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void calcProduct() {
        double d1 = Double.parseDouble(field1.getText());
        double d2 = Double.parseDouble(field2.getText());
        double prod = d1 * d2;
        resultField.setText(String.valueOf(prod));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                VerifierEg eg = new VerifierEg();
                eg.createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
    * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11818946/230513
    */
    private class MyInputVerifier extends InputVerifier {

        private JTextField field;
        private double value;

        public MyInputVerifier(JTextField field) {
            this.field = field;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldYieldFocus(JComponent input) {
            if (verify(input)) {
                field.setText(String.valueOf(value));
                calcProduct();
                status.setText(OK);
                return true;
            } else {
                field.setText(ZERO);
                field.selectAll();
                status.setText("Please enter a number.");
                return false;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
            try {
                value = Double.parseDouble(field.getText());
                return true;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```